# How do I find the actual values referred to in this MSDN documentation?

Tags: c++, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged, msdn

I'm using C# to marshall/pinvoke code in user32.dll

I have a specific question and learning the answer should help me a great deal.

Question: Referring to the below MSDN documentation, it mentions one of the input parameters for the GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes, "Flags", could accept one of three values.  One of these, for example, is called QDC_ALL_PATHS.  However, it's obvious that "Flags" is a UINT32 and therefore there should be an actual defined integer value for "QDC_ALL_PATHS".

Where do I get this information? I.e., where is the actual defined integer value of "QDC_ALL_PATHS" as per User32.dll so that I can implement it in my code?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566772(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a simple Windows C++ project, type somewhere in the code `QDC_ALL_PATHS`, press <kbd>F12</kbd> (or right click and "Go To Definition"):

```
#define QDC_ALL_PATHS                   0x00000001
#define QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS           0x00000002
#define QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT            0x00000004
```

Comment: Wondering why MSDN doesn't provide these information

Comment: I want to know the value of DI_NEEDREBOOT mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552346(v=vs.85).aspx) and your approach doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: @Elderry See `#include <Setupapi.h>`: `#define DI_NEEDREBOOT 0x00000100L`.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) -> Find "`QDC_ALL_PATHS`" in *.h

`WinGdi.h`:

```
#define QDC_ALL_PATHS                   0x00000001
#define QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS           0x00000002
#define QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT            0x00000004
```